# How to implement FIFO with a ORM?

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, activerecord, doctrine, fifo

I'm developing a web POS using [Symfony](https://symfony.com/). The system works, but I'm worried about the database. I'm storing the product qty as a float, this is because some products can be sold in qty like 0.3, 0.2, 0.99, 1.69, etc. Like bread. When i save the sell I call to a save method. That save method use a `foreach` to walk a array collection of details , that detail is a entity that has the qty, the price, and the product, every sale has at least one detail. Anyways to update the qty I just do this:

```
detail->getProduct()->setQty(detail->getProduct()->getQty - detail->getQty )
```

Is easy to update and delete a sale. But it does not support FIFO or LIFO.

Now I want so support FIFO and LIFO at first I tried to create a Stock Entity, like this

```
Stock{
var  productId ;
var cost;
var sell; 
var detail;
}
```

and a detail table which holds this:

```
Detail{
var  product[];
var  price;
  
}
```

And the sell class,

```
Sell{
  var Details[];
  var total;
}
```

So for example for a sell of a 3 units of x product.  I will look for 3 entities of Stock with no detail added yet, and if is FIFO they results should be ordered by id ASC.

But still for products like bread I don't know how can work, I cannot have 1000 entities representing 1kg of bread in the database XD.

How should this be implemented FIFO with a ORM?

Comment: You do not implement a FIFO with an ORM. You implement a FIFO with a message queue. Attempts to implement a FIFO in a RDBMS will fail.

Comment: not sure if the FIFO that you are talking about is the same of FIFO from inventory trading system.

Comment: Generally you may have to use `FIFO`, `LIFO` or `FEFO` (first-expiring first-out) sort for stock, although LIFO is very uncommon (and legally disallowed in some countries as well).  You will have to store receiving and expiry dates on `Stock` and sort by those fields if you have to implement these.